# regex to match the closing tags by ignoring inner tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to capture the image tag of MediaWiki format, e.g,

> **[[** Image:Justus Sustermans - Portrait of Galileo Galilei
> (Uffizi).jpg|left|thumb|upright|[[Galileo]] is often referred to as
> the Father of [[modern astronomy]], portrait by [[Justus
> Sustermans]]**]]**

I have to ignore the inner `[[...]]` to match the whole (shown by bold `[[` and `]]`). I came up with

```
\[\[Image:((?:[^]]*+(?:(?!\[\[)|(?R))*+)*+)\]\]
```

but it stops at the first `]]`.

[Fiddle](https://regexr.com/5sm1t)

Comment: @anubhava matching the whole text quoted above (out of the wiki text).

Comment: So, you do not need to actually capture the text between `[[Image:` and `]]`? Why did you use a capturing group then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you could look for balanced square brackets but restrict the rule for both ends using lookarounds:

```
(?=\[\[Image:)(\[(?:[^][]|(?1))*])(?<=]])
```

- `(?=\[\[Image:)` Lookahead to search for a string starts with `[[Image:`
- `(\[(?:[^][]|(?1))*])` Balanced nested square brackets using recursion
- `(?<=]])` Lookbehind to search for a string ends with `]]`

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/OSPgfX/1/)

---

If you don't care the brackets inside are balanced or not but just want to make an assumption and exclude `[[ ]]` pairs. This one should do the trick:

```
\[\[Image:(?:\[\[.*?]]|.)*?]]
```

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/OT4Dzu/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```php
\[\[Image:((?:[^][]+|(\[\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*]]))*)]]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ksIBvS/3).

*Details*:

- `\[\[Image:` - a literal `[[Image:` string
- `((?:[^][]+|(\[\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*]]))*)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:[^][]|(\[\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*]]))*` - zero or more occurrences of

    - `[^][]+` - any one or more chars other than `[` and `]`
    - `|` - or
    - `(\[\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*]])` - Group 2 (technical, for recursion): a substring between nested `[[` and `]]`
- `]]` - a `]]` string.

*NOTE*: If you are sure there can only be a single nested level of double square parentheses, you can use

```php
\[\[Image:([^][]*(?:\[\[[^][]*]][^][]*)*)]]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ksIBvS/2). Here, `([^][]*(?:\[\[[^][]*]][^][]*)*)` captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, then matches zero or more occurrences of a substring between double square brackets with no square brackets inside, and then zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`.